# SQL Server : cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm currently getting the error:

> Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery

The full query:

```
query = "SELECT * FROM (SELECT" +
" IDWebsite = Websites.Id, " +
" Websites.Title, " +
" Websites.Description, " +
" Websites.Url, " +
" Websites.BannerURL,  " +
" (Select Count(*) From Votes where WebsiteID = Websites.Id) as TotalVotes, " +
" AVG(ISNULL((Select Rating From WebsiteRating where WebsiteID = Websites.Id), 5)) as Rating, " +
" Users.Username, " +
" Websites.ID, " +
" (Select Count(*) From Redirects where WebsiteID = Websites.Id) as websiteCount, " +
" RowNum = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Websites.ID) " +
" FROM Websites " +
" INNER JOIN Users ON Websites.UserID = Users.Id " +
" LEFT OUTER JOIN Votes AS Votes_1 ON Votes_1.WebsiteID = Websites.Id  " +
" LEFT OUTER JOIN Redirects AS Redirects_1 ON Redirects_1.WebsiteID = Websites.Id " +
" LEFT OUTER JOIN WebsiteRating AS WebsiteRating_1 ON WebsiteRating_1.WebsiteID = Websites.Id " +
" GROUP BY Websites.Title, Websites.Description, Websites.Url, Websites.BannerURL , Users.Username, Websites.ID" +
") as Table1 " +
"WHERE RowNum > " + number + " And RowNum <= " + amount + " " +
"Order by TotalVotes ";
```

The line causing the problem is:

```
" AVG(ISNULL((Select Rating From WebsiteRating where WebsiteID = Websites.Id), 5)) as Rating, " +
```

I tried to fix it myself with tutorials, but unfortunately I was getting various other errors. I'm still a beginner, so I don't have a lot of knowledge about SQL unfortunately..

If anyone could help me out, i would be very thankful!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't concatenate the query. That leaves you vulnerable to SQL injection.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with your subqueries.  It is quite difficult to read/modify a query that is presented as a long set of string concatenations.  It is better to just show the query in the question.

Consider this subquery:

```
(Select Count(*) From Votes where WebsiteID = Websites.Id) as TotalVotes
```

The problem is that `Websites.Id` is not well defined by the outer query.  You have three choices.  First, you can change it to:

```
(Select Count(*) From Votes where WebsiteID = max(Websites.Id)) as TotalVotes
```

Or, you could include `Websites.Id` in the `group by` clause.

Or, you could actually do the comparison logic on the fields in the `group by`.